# Всегда отображать значок приложения в трее (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi

Приложение имеет трей-меню. Нужно, чтобы его значок был всегда видимым в трее, как например, значки сети, выбора языка, или звука..

Также нужно сделать то же самое со сторонним приложением, к коду которого доступа нет.

**С какими параметрами нужно создавать `NOTIFYICONDATA`, или может какое-то специальное сообщение есть... или в реестре прописать?**

Comment: Есть специальные утилиты, которые умеют сворачивать любое приложение в трей.

Comment: Нет, @insolor, тут вопрос не в том, чтобы спрятать в трей, а в том, чтобы при отключенной опции "Всегда отображать все значки и уведомления на панели задач" значок отображался развернутым (всегда виден, т.е. не попадал в группу "свернутых").

Comment: @mega, тогда ответ - средствами Windows (начиная с XP, когда появилась возможность убирать лишние значки в трее) можно указать, какие значки показывать всегда, какие скрывать.

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос с решением, можно попробовать: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?306661-How-to-always-show-an-icon-in-system-tray

Comment: Еще вариант: https://superuser.com/questions/199436/make-windows-show-icon-and-notifications-by-default-but-let-you-hide-some